# 64-bit compiler error on va_list variable

Tags: 64-bit, variadic-functions

i have compiled the below code in 32-bit and 64-bit.
no issues in 32-bit, but i am getting compiler error in 64-bit mode.
please help me in removing the error without using slandered function like va_arg.

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int, ...);
int main(void)
{
     printf("Sum of 10, 20 and 30 = %d\n",  sum(8, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80) );
 printf("Sum of 4, 20, 25 and 30 = %d\n",  sum(4, 4, 20, 25, 30) );

 return 0;
}

int sum(int num_args, ...)
{
   int val = 0;
   va_list ap;
   int i;

   va_start(ap, num_args);
   for(i = 0; i < num_args; i++)
   {
       val += *(int *)((ap += sizeof(int)) - sizeof(int));
   }
   va_end(ap);

   return val;
  }


  error is below.

   [avinta@la-lnx61dev01 ~]$ gcc -m64 var_list1.c
  var_list1.c: In function âsumâ:
  var_list1.c:28: error: invalid operands to binary + (have âva_listâ and     âlong unsigned intâ)
  [avinta@la-lnx61dev01 ~]$
```

Comment: "...without using slandered function"? What's "slandered function" and why is `va_arg` suddenly "slandered"? And how is it more "slandered" than `va_start` and `va_end`, which you are already using? And where did you even get the idea that you can apply arithmetic operations to `va_list` object?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not portable. Using `va_arg` is the only way allowed by the standard. You are relying on the details of how `va_list` is implemented on one architecture, which is not the same as how it is on a different architecture.